# what does this declaration in JS do "=>"

Tags: javascript, declaration

```
x = (i) => {....
```

is than short hand for

```
function x (i){....
```

wtf if i try to google "=>" i am getting ZERO results ?!

Comment: It's an arrow function. What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a fat arrow notation.

New way of writing functions in ES6

```
x = (i) => 4;

x() ;//4
```

Benefits of fat arrow functions is that you dont have to bind the functions with this operator.Arrow functions use the same this as the function which wraps them